# Thinking Sphinx searching search across all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

i've implemented search for induvidual models and it works.
Now i have my home page which has a form that has fields from several models of my application but searching one field at a time doesn't yield any result on the home page although i can see the query....(searching for tv_show name)

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "name"=>"count", "broadcast_date_from"=>"", "broadcast_date_to"=>"", "gender"=>"", "organization_id"=>"", "position_id"=>"", "alignment"=>"", "commit"=>"Generate"}
 Sphinx Query (1.0ms)  SELECT * FROM `episode_core`, `organization_core`, `person_core`, `position_core`, `profession_core`, `segment_core`, `tv_show_core` WHERE MATCH('*count*') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `last_name` ASC, first_name ASC LIMIT 0, 20
 Sphinx  Found 0 results
 Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/home (3.0ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 12.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

when search the model `tv_show` i have a result.

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "name"=>"count", "channel"=>"", "starting_time"=>"", "ending_time"=>"", "commit"=>"Search"}
 Sphinx Query (0.9ms)  SELECT * FROM `tv_show_core` WHERE MATCH('*count*') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `tv_name` ASC LIMIT 0, 20
 Sphinx  Found 2 results
 TvShow Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tv_shows".* FROM "tv_shows" WHERE "tv_shows"."id" IN (9, 4)
 Rendered tv_shows/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.5ms)
 Rendered tv_shows/_search.html.erb (0.9ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 68ms (Views: 66.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

So why is there a difference?

**global search**   no result

```
@results = ThinkingSphinx.search.search "#{params[:name]} ", 
:star => /[\w@:]+/u, 
:order => 'last_name ASC, first_name ASC',
:page     => params[:page], 
:per_page => 20
```

**model search**    return results

```
@tv_shows = TvShow.search "#{params[:name]} #{params[:channel]} ", 
     :star => /[\w@:]+/u,  
     :order => 'tv_name ASC', 
     :page => params[:page], 
     :per_page => 20
```

***UPDATE***
 ok removing the `:order => 'last_name ASC, first_name ASC',` get me somewhere.

Have another question
how do you make it query a specific model depending on the field used in the form?

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "name"=>"count", "broadcast_date_from"=>"", "broadcast_date_to"=>"", "gender"=>"", "organization_id"=>"", "position_id"=>"", "alignment"=>"", "commit"=>"Generate"}
 Profession Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "professions".* FROM "professions" ORDER BY name
 Organization Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations" ORDER BY name
 Position Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" ORDER BY name
 Sphinx Query (1.7ms)  SELECT * FROM `episode_core`, `episode_delta`, `organization_core`, `organization_delta`, `person_core`, `person_delta`, `position_core`, `position_delta`, `profession_core`, `profession_delta`, `segment_core`, `segment_delta`, `tv_show_core`, `tv_show_delta` WHERE MATCH('*count*') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 20
 Sphinx  Found 4 results
 Organization Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" IN (109)
 Position Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE "positions"."id" IN (164)
 TvShow Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tv_shows".* FROM "tv_shows" WHERE "tv_shows"."id" IN (4, 9)
```

Here i am just using the tv_show field which refer to the TvShow model.
Adding a conditon is not helping....`:condition =>  {:tv_name => params[:name]}`

any insight appreciated.

**Response**(just in case)

Needed to add in the global search view :

```
<% for result in @results %>  
  <% if result.class.name == "Organization" %>
      <%= render :partial => "organizations/result", :locals => { :result => result } %>
  <% elsif result.class.name == "Position" %>
      <%= render :partial => "positions/result", :locals => { :result => result } %>
  <% elsif result.class.name == "TvShow" %>
      <%= render :partial => "tv_shows/result", :locals => { :result => result } %>                 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and create partial ( _result.html.erb ) for each model in view folder to print the different fields (The partials are optional).

Comment: Does the TvShow model have attributes called `last_name` and `first_name`? If you're searching across models, any attributes you use for sorting need to exist in all index definitions.

Comment: ok i removed :order => 'last_name ASC, first_name ASC' and it works